# Link Error 'target machine "THUMB" requires "/WINDOWSCE"' on static library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am moving a Embedded Visual C++ project to VS2005.  When I compile the project I get this error:  `fatal error CVT1109: target machine "THUMB" requires "/WINDOWSCE"  CVTRES`.  Goggling this just left me more confused.  Most stated I needed to add the linker option `/WINDOWSCE`.  My issue is there is no linker options in Configuration Properties for a static library.

I left out I am also getting this link error:

```
LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file invalid or corrupt
```

**Update** The error above happens when the the output windows says it is 'Creating library...'. I believe this has to do with the resource file in the project.  If I remove the rc file I can create the library.  Why is the rc file causing the CVTRES error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally Resolved**  I opened

Project Properties --> Configuration Properties --> Librarian --> Command Line

Than I added the following line:

```
/subsystem:$(CESubsystem) /MACHINE:THUMB
```

I would of sworn I tried that from the start, thank the heavens I found the solution hope it helps someone else.